# custom tooltips overflowing out of the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, tooltip

I am building out a styleguide and currently, I am working on the tooltips for elements.

I am using SCSS and trying not to use anything other than CSS or pure JavaScript, I do not want to use ANY framework or library as dependencies must be kept to a minimum.

Here is a screenshot of the current issue:

[image]
As you can see in the bottom left, the tooltip overflows out of the page.

I need to find a way to make sure that the whole tooltip ALWAYS stays within the viewport.

Here is my current SCSS and HTML:

```css
[data-toggle="tooltip"] {
    position   : relative;
    display    : inline-block;
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform  : translateX(-50%);
    &:hover {
        &::after,
        &::before {
            display: block;
        }
    }
    &::after,
    &::before {
        position: absolute;
        display : none;
    }
    &.tooltip-right {
        &::after {
            content      : "";
            left         : calc(100% + 5px);
            top          : 50%;
            transform    : translateY(-50%);
            background   : $tooltipBg;
            opacity      : 0.8;
            color        : white;
            padding      : 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        &::before {
            width        : 0;
            height       : 0;
            border-right : 5px solid transparentize($tooltipBg, 0.2);
            border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
            border-top   : 5px solid transparent;
            top          : 0;
            left         : 100%;
            content      : "";
            top          : 50%;
            transform    : translateY(-50%);
        }
    }
    &.tooltip-left {
        &::after {
            content      : "dhfgdahfgekfdshkfgdskhgfdhkbfjhsdgfjhdsgf";
            left         : 0;
            top          : 50%;
            transform    : translate(calc((-100%) - 5px), -50%);
            background   : $tooltipBg;
            opacity      : 0.8;
            color        : white;
            padding      : 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        &::before {
            width        : 0;
            height       : 0;
            border-left  : 5px solid transparentize($tooltipBg, 0.2);
            border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
            border-top   : 5px solid transparent;
            top          : 0;
            left         : -5px;
            content      : "";
            top          : 50%;
            transform    : translateY(-50%);
        }
    }
    &.tooltip-bottom {
        &::after {
            content      : "";
            left         : 50%;
            transform    : translate(-50%, 5px);
            background   : $tooltipBg;
            opacity      : 0.8;
            color        : white;
            padding      : 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        &::before {
            width        : 0;
            height       : 0;
            border-left  : 5px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 5px solid transparentize($tooltipBg, 0.2);
            border-right : 5px solid transparent;
            left         : 50%;
            bottom       : 0;
            content      : "";
            transform    : translate(-50%, 5px);
        }
    }
    &.tooltip-top {
        &::after {
            content      : "";
            left         : 50%;
            top          : 0;
            transform    : translate(-50%, -25px);
            background   : #4C4C4C;
            opacity      : 0.8;
            color        : white;
            padding      : 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        &::before {
            width       : 0;
            height      : 0;
            border-left : 5px solid transparent;
            border-top  : 5px solid transparentize($tooltipBg, 0.2);
            border-right: 5px solid transparent;
            left        : 50%;
            content     : "";
            transform   : translate(-50%, -5px);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<section>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="title">Tooltips</h1>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="tooltip-container tooltip-left" data-toggle="tooltip" data-tooltip-direction="left" data-tooltip-text="I'm a tooltip yo!">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="meow" class="circle center">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="tooltip-container tooltip-right" data-toggle="tooltip" data-tooltip-direction="left" data-tooltip-text="I'm a tooltip yo!">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="meow" class="circle center">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="tooltip-container tooltip-top" data-toggle="tooltip" data-tooltip-direction="left" data-tooltip-text="I'm a tooltip yo!">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="meow" class="circle center">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <div class="tooltip-container tooltip-bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" data-tooltip-direction="left" data-tooltip-text="I'm a tooltip yo!">
                            <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" alt="meow" class="circle center">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
```

As mentioned above, the solution must not be a framework or library. I have tried different positioning (block, etc), widths, but nothing seems to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Javascript is required in this case to figure out if the content of the tooltip is going beyond physically viewable boundaries

Comment: Provide a solution?